# Why werent/arent revolver cylinders used as magazines for reloading?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The question is regarding reloading revolver guns.
You either shove cartridge by cartridge, or use these fancy clips that allow shoving all 6 or 8 cartridges at once.

I understand that the cylinder is actually attached to the weapon in a way you cant just pull it out. The question is exactly this, why not?

The cylinders can get pretty hot when firing (I believe so), which makes reloading bothersome, even with the clip.

Ignoring pricing problems, wouldnt it be possible to design a revolver where you can treat cylinders as ammo magazines, and just pull the empty one out and shove another one in, on demand?

Answer (score 1):

Firearms with slides and magazines were designed to provide the reload capability you seek.

They are not revolvers.  I'm guessing you want a revolver for a reason.  Chances are pretty high that the reason would be somewhat compromised if the structural and alignment benefits of a non-removable cylinder were lost.  You could compensate for it with additional alignment mechanisms, but you lose the simplicity of a revolver at that point.

There are firearms that fill that niche already and do so much more cost-effectively than multiple cylinders precision machined to replace one another as magazines.  Aligning long items is easier - a longer lever will scale the same linear tolerance to a smaller angular one.  A slide takes advantage of this.

Answer (score 1):

The Remington 1858 revolver was bult like this, but it was a percussion cap black powder pistol, loading was hard, and you **had** to remove the cylinder to load it (it was loaded from the muzzle end of the cylinder).  As brass cartridges came into the fore, the need dropped.  Note that early single action revolvers tended to have a loading door and single shell loading.  Break action pistols (like the Webley) and swingout cylinders (like almost everything today) dropped the need as well.

Clint reloads his 1858 at the end of [Pale Rider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCKDsplALDc&ab_channel=JimmieDee)

From a cost standpoint, the cylinder is an expensive bit of the device to want to provide as spares.  As soon as semi-automatic pistols came into widespread use, magazines made of stamped metal were much much cheaper than milled revolver cylinders.